# Nested static class

Tags: java

```
public class ShapesGeometry {

    public static Circle Circle = new Circle();
    public static Rectangle Rectangle = new Rectangle();
    public static Triangle Triangle = new Triangle();

    public static class Circle {
        public double GetArea(double Radius) {
            return (3.14159 * Radius * Radius);
        }

        public double GetCircumFerence(double Radius) {
            return (2 * 3.14159 * Radius);
        }
    }//End Class Circle

    public static class Rectangle {
        public double GetArea(double Length, double Width) {
            return (Length * Width);
        }

        public double GetCircumFerence(double Length, double Width) {
            return (2 * Length + 2 * Width);
        }
    }//End Class Rectangle

    public static class Triangle {
        public double GetArea(double Base, double Height) {
            return (0.5 * Base * Height);
        }

        public double GetCircumFerence(double Side1, double Side2, double Side3) {
            return (Side1 + Side2 + Side3);
        }
    }// End Class Triangle 
}
```

So I started to take some private lectures to improve my skills in Java programming, and I feel like that my teacher is talking nonsense (maybe I am wrong). In the example above (nested static classes) I have some questions to ask you.

1. Is the example shown above, a good example for introducing nested static classes?
2. My teacher then talks about inheritance, and I really can't see any inheritance? Like the classes are not inheriting anything from what I can see.

Comment: BTW: Java naming convention would be to start mehtods with lowercase letter. It is much less confusing that way.

Comment: ^ Same goes for field names.

Comment: The question is *what* he was saying about inheritance? Just saying that he was "talking about inheritance" doesn't tell us much. Perhaps he was discussing the potential to inherit from this class etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there is no inheritance in the example, and it is not a good example to introduce nested static classes. I would expect to use 3 independent classes (and a base class) for the concept of inheritance (where geometry shapes are a canonical example). But of course it is hard to comment without knowing what your teacher actually said while explaining the code.

And a static nested class should only be introduced after showing the non-static variants.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is the example shown above a good example for introducing nested static classes

No there doesn't seem to be a reason to make them static, the classes should be in their own files and not nested

> 2. My teacher then talks about inheritance, and I really can't see any inheritance? like the classes is not inheriting anything from what i can see.

There is no inheritance here.

A good example of how to use nested static classes properly is the `java.util.Collections` class which has many nested **private** static classes which implement different Collection objects like

[Collections.emptyList()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.emptyList%28%29) -A special implementation of `List` that is always empty

[Collections.UnmodifableCollection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.UnmodifiableCollection) - A special implementation of `Collection` that can't have elements added or removed

Answer (score 0):

1. Not a good example for introducing nested classes, because the declarations you proposed are not motivated by any plausible use of these classes.
2. You're right, no inheritance here.

Answer (score 0):

A static class created inside a class is called static nested class in Java. This example does not shows the real use of static class. Here is an example:

```
class TestOuter {
    static int data = 100; 

    static class Inner {
        void message() {
            System.out.println("data is "+data);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        TestOuter.Inner obj = new TestOuter.Inner();  
        obj.message();  
    }  
}
```

For your second point, there is no inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an example of nested static class AND inheritance the first example I would suggest is to look at the Josh Bloch Builder pattern (e.g. on Effective Java 2 book).

```
public interface Builder<T> { T build(); }

public class MyClass {

  private MyClass() {}

  public static class MyBuilder implements Builder<MyClass> { /*...*/ }
  /*...*/
}
```